# How do I make a "Hide function" in a Frame to make some things visible and others invisible? (Java)

Tags: function, visible, jdeveloper, invisible

I'm trying to do an User Interface to complement a simple programming code.

I decided to do everything in one Frame instead of different kinds.

Instead of just pasting the code here from the frame (it's a lot!) I will try to explain what it looks like:

I have three different headings: **Customer**, **Boat** and **Order**

Below each heading I have several different labels next to several textfields, kinda like this:

```
 Customer                   Boat                       Order

 Name: [textfield]          Model: [textfield]         Name: [textfield]
 Adress: [textfield]        Price: [textfield]         Model: [textfield]
```

---

As you probably can imagine it looks kind of stupid when you can see all textfields and labels connected to the different headings.

**When I start the application at first, I want the frame ONLY to show the actual headings "Customer", "Boat", "Order".

All the other labels, textfields, buttons that are connected to the headings should be invisible. Next to the Headings I want to add some sort of button/JRadioButton/Checkbox (one for each heading).
So when you "check/fill" the button/checkbox for one of the headings I want all the things connected to it to become visible. But all the others connected to the the other headings to remain invisible.**

How do I make this possible? What Component should I use? What should the code look like?

Thanks for the help!

/Chris

Comment: Please tell us which technology you are using (e.g. swing ) and which Java version you are using.

Comment: Oh sorry! it's JDeveloper, AWT :)

Comment: Which jdev version? Why do you use awt?